# Estimate the second derivative of a Jacobi field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading *Local convexity and nonnegative curvature-Gromov's proof of the sphere theorem* of Eschenburg recently. In his proof in Lemma 4.3, he consider the following question:

Suppose $0\leq K\leq k$ on $U\subset M$. Fix $x\in U_r$, where the convexity radius on $U$ is less than $r$ and $U_r=\{x\in U|B_r(x)\subset U\}$. $x\in T_xM$ with $\|v\|=1$. Let $c$ be a geodesic with $c(0)=x$ and $c'(0)=v$. For any $u\in T_xM$ with $\|u\|<r$. Let $a_u(s,t)=\operatorname{exp}_{c(t)}sP_tu$ where $P_t$ denotes the parallel dis[lacement along $c$. Let $U=\frac{d}{dt}a_u$, $V=\frac{d}{dt}a_u$. Thus $V_t(0)=c'(t)$, $V_t'(0)=\frac{D}{dt}U(0,t)=0$. By Rauch's theorem, we get $\|V\|<\|v\|=1$.

Then he said that $\|V''\|=\|R(V,U)U\|\leq kr^2$, but I think that we can only get $g(R(V,U)U,V)\leq kr^2$. So how did he arrived at this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be the unit vector in the same direction as $R(V,U)U.$ Then
\begin{align*}
2|R(V,U)U|
&=2g(R(V,U)U,W)\\
&=g(R(V+W,U)U,V+W)
- g(R(V,U)U,V)
- g(R(W,U)U,W)\\
& \le 2kr^2-0-0=2kr^2.
\end{align*}